# Insert HTML inside of $db->Execute command

Tags: php, html, sql

I have this command:

```
$result = $db->Execute("select id,name,description,requirements,display_condition from works order by id");
```

And I want to insert `< td >` INSIDE of the command, that way it enters all of the above select information into a table box.

I tried inserting `echo "< td >";` right before the command, but it only creates ONE table box.

Screenie displaying my code and what is happening:

[image]

Comment: Can you add some more code.

Comment: @Class here is an image displaying what is happening. Along with the code. http://i.imgur.com/GbcrDXs.png

Comment: $result will probably be an array or a database object, which you'll have to 'walk over' to get the values. Use foreach to do this. It is very dependant on what kind of an object $db->Execute returns though... To get a complete answer I agree with @Class: add some more code.

Comment: @user249165 add it to your question. and add more code before and after your `Execute` line. Not in image format.

Comment: @Class There you go bud, edited my first post, is that what you mean? Otherwise, here is the URL for the image.. http://i.imgur.com/IgEWi6b.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute something like this:

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
$query = 'SELECT id, name, description, requirements FROM works ORDER BY id';
$rows = $db->query($query, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
while( $entry = $rows->fetch() ) {
  echo "<tr>"
      ."<td>".$entry->id."</td>"
      ."<td>".$entry->name."</td>"
      ."<td>".$entry->description."</td>"
      ."<td>".$entry->requirements."</td>"
      ."</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This code allows to populate the data from the DB into a table.

BTW, if you have to skip some rows in the DB by analyzing the "display_condition" field, you would better do it in the SQL query. (I mean in the "$query = ..." line)